# CSRF token and multiple server

Tags: angularjs, spring, spring-security, load-balancing, csrf-protection

I have implemented Spring Security with CSRF token in my AngularJs and Spring Application. Below is the Code to enable CSRF token filter.

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
             http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/apps", "/sites", "/users").authenticated()
            .and()
            .csrf()
            .csrfTokenRepository(csrfTokenRepository())
            .and()
            .addFilterAfter(new CsrfHeaderFilter(), CsrfFilter.class);
}
private CsrfTokenRepository csrfTokenRepository() {
            HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository repository = new HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository();
            repository.setHeaderName("X-XSRF-TOKEN");
            return repository;
}

public class CsrfHeaderFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
@Override
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
    CsrfToken token = (CsrfToken) request.getAttribute(CsrfToken.class
            .getName());
    if (token != null) {
        Cookie cookie = WebUtils.getCookie(request, "X-XSRF-TOKEN");
        if (cookie == null || token != null && !token.equals(cookie.getValue())) {
            cookie = new Cookie("X-XSRF-TOKEN", token.getToken());
            cookie.setPath("/");
            response.addCookie(cookie);
        }
    }
    filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
}
```

Using the above code my application works fine in local Tomcat Server(Spring Boot Server) and Wildfly server. But when I tried to deploy the same code in Development Server which use multiple IP address, I'm getting **Invalid CSRF Token** error.

Below is the Screenshot
[image]
From this screenshot IP address in `JSESSIONID` in Request and Response are different. Please suggest solution for this issue.
**UPDATE**
After stopping load balance server(Currently only one server running), I am not facing CSRF issue. Please suggest solution for load balance server issue.

**UPDATE**
After analyzing we came to know that, that we can use Sticky Session to resolve this issue. But as per our client requirements we cannot use Sticky Session.

Comment: What is the spring security version you are using and can you add  the JSP(View) component coding here?

Comment: We are using `spring-boot-starter-security` Version `1.2.5.Release`. As we are using AngularJS we don't have JSP page. By default `JSESSIONID` and `XSRF-TOKEN` are appended in Header.

Comment: Still we are not able to find solution for this issue. Is there anyone resolved this issue without using Sticky Session.